# I want to get a piece of state for a sibling reducer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux

I have a list of reducers in my combineReducer:

```
export default createRootReducer =>
  combineReducers({
    profile,
    settings,
  });
```

I want to get some state from profile, into settings, as I need the current user id, when making an API call.

My settings reducer:

```
export default (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case Actions.SettingsSave:
            api.patch("settingsAPI", { body: action.payload, params: { user_id } });
            let finalPayload = Object.assign({}, state, action.payload);
            return finalPayload;
        default:
            return state;
    }
};
```

How would I get the data from profile into settings? Is there any way? I tried to get it directly from the store, but that's not allowed in a reducer that is in the middle of execution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a `getState` in the action creator and pass it in through the action. Something like

```
export default saveSettings(params){
   const currState = store.getState()
   return {
       type: "SAVE_SETTINGS",
       foo: params,
       profileSlice: currState.settings
   }
}
```

Comment: I ultimately went with this approach, though I am not certain if this or the thunk approach above would be superior architecturally.

Answer (score 1):

You would probably need to use [thunk](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk) for accessing your global state. Here's an example:

```
export function updateProduct(product) {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    const { accountDetails } = getState();

    dispatch({
      type: UPDATE_PRODUCT,
      stateOfResidenceId: accountDetails.stateOfResidenceId,
      product,
    });
  };
}
```